# Kali tools on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, kali

Is it possible to install Kali tools on Raspbian?
I have tried Katoolin but I keep getting a segmentation fault error when fixing the dependencies and getting stuck in a loop where "it is not going to be installed" because I don't know how to fix the error...

Has anyone tried doing this and have it work?

The errors seems to have something to do with libwebkit2gtk-4 0-37 (and it's dependencies) and that segmentation fault when the apt is doing something with libc-dev (or something similar, I forgot and my ssh client doesn't have that stored on the history any more).

Sorry for the bad formatting, it's midnight and I started trying to figure this out at 7pm... And I have been re-flashing my microsd card every time the error comes up which took a long time...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's easy to install Kali on Raspbian. Follow the guide [here](https://opensourceforu.com/2016/11/katoolin-installing-kali-linux-tools-debian-based-os/) or do the below:

1. If you don't have Git run `sudo apt-get install git`
2. Become root, run `sudo -i` or `su` then enter password
3. Git clone, run `git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git`
   and `cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin`
4. Make katoolin executable: `chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin`
5. To run Katoolin, `sudo katoolin`

Note that it is **imperative** that you **remove all Kali Linux tools before you update** or upgrade **Raspbian.**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to install to `/usr/local/bin` instead?  This way you have no potential conflicts with anything the distro is prone to install or update, and stuff in `/usr/local/bin` has precedence in `$PATH`.

Comment: Perhaps, but their page on Github reccomends /usr/bin/katoolin, so the paths in their python scripts might be absolute.

Comment: I already tried that and it wouldn't work, because there is packages with no installation candidate, and even after removing those packages there was dependencies issues with libwebkit2gtk and another package called enchant (or maybe libenchant, it has the word enchant somewhere). I already know how to use katoolin because I have used it multiple time on x86 Ubuntu. BTW, I'm on a pi zero.

Comment: Surely it would be easier to use the official Kali build for a Raspberry https://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi

Comment: I actually tried installing Kali directly but it didn't come with a desktop and installing a desktop results in a black empty screen...

Comment: Which desktop did you install?